# Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Error::get_item_quantity()

Tags: php, fatal-error

I've implemented a way to show the Twitter feed without a plugin. It's worked for weeks(months even, on a different site), but is now giving me trouble. Here is the error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Error::get_item_quantity() in ... home.php on line 27

Line 27: $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(3);

```
<?php
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rss = fetch_feed('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=urbanpalatela');
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(3);
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
?>

<ul>
<?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No items.</li>';
else
// Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink.
foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
<li>
<a href='<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>'>
<?php echo str_replace('UrbanPalateLA: ', '&bull;', $item->get_title()); ?>
</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Any ideas what could be causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are probably receiving a WP_Error on first run.

around the `$maxitems` and `$rss_items` lines, add:

```
if( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) {
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(3);
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
}
```

As seen in the [example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error is now gone, but the feed simply says "No items." instead of showing the tweets. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't used this before. In the WordPress codex, they have this line above the `fetch_feed()`: `
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');`. Perhaps try including the feed.php file, it may include some things required for this to work.

Comment: Hm, I do have that in the second line.

Comment: As mentioned on a below comment, I tried adding the link you are using to Google Reader and it gave me an error. Perhaps you mispelled the username.. >_>

Answer (score 0):

The twitter url does not seem to be valid. You can prevent this error twofold because it relies on a 3rd party.

First check if the feed is empty before you use `$maxitems` , not after.

For example:

```
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rss = fetch_feed('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/....');

if ($rss->get_item_quanity != 0) { 
   $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(3);
   //rest of your code..
} else { 
   echo 'No feed available'; }
```

Edit: Eric's example is probably better because it will be handled by WP using `if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) )`

Second you twitter url is not returning anything, thus the error, this could be because the API has changed, you will have to refer to the twitter docs, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily anything to do with Twitter- I'm using this exact bit of code on a different website without any issues. The only difference is the username being used.

Comment: You can see that the direct link you're using, https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=urbanpalatela does not return anything.